# How to check if current coordinates are within a radius of other coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have latitude and longitude of a fixed location. I want to check if another location (latitude and longitude) is close enough (50-100 meters) to the fixed location. I use iPhone to get current location.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method [– distanceFromLocation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distancefromlocation) of *CLLocation* is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 7):

```
distanceFromCurrentLocation = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:destinationlocation]/convertToKiloMeter;
if(distanceFromCurrentLocation < 100 && distanceFromLocation > .500)
{
    NSLog(@"Yeah, this place is inside my circle");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Oops!! its too far");
}
```

This finds the air distance, or we can say, straight line distance only.
Hope you are not looking for road distance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it in Swift using CoreLocation. You just compare 2 different locations using the `.distance(from: )` method on a location that is of type `CLLocation`. Make sure **both** locations are of type `CLLocation`

```
import CoreLocation

let someOtherLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: someOtherLat,
                                               longitude: someOtherLon)

guard let usersCurrentLocation: CLLocation = locationManager.location else { return }

                                                       // **the distance(from: ) is right here **
let distanceInMeters: CLLocationDistance = usersCurrentLocation.distance(from: someOtherLocation)

if distanceInMeters < 100 {

    // this user is pretty much in the same area as the otherLocation
} else {

   // this user is at least over 100 meters outside the otherLocation
}
```

this isn't necessary but maybe you need to save the lats and lons for later for another comparison. I know I needed them

```
let usersCurrentLat: CLLocationDegrees = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude // not neccessary but this is how you get the lat
let usersCurrentLon: CLLocationDegrees = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude // not neccessary but this is how you get the lon

let someOtherLocationLat: CLLocationDegrees = someOtherLocationLocation.coordinate.latitude // not neccessary but this is how you get the lat
let someOtherLocationLon: CLLocationDegrees = someOtherLocationtLocation.coordinate.longitude // not neccessary but this is how you get the lon


let usersLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: usersCurrentLat,
                                           longitude: usersCurrentLon)

let otherLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: someOtherLocationLat,
                                           longitude: someOtherLocationLon)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CLLocation *location;// = init...;
double distance = [location distanceFromLocation:otherLoc]; //in meters
```

Answer (score 1):

Although i Upvoted Empty Stack answer..
If you need more help here is the code..

**Be the CLLocationManagerDelegate and then in your implementation class.**

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{


            int distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
            if(distance >50 && distance <100)
            {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Distance"
                                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i meters",distance]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Deepukjayan answer, use CLLocation to define a reference before using his answer:

```
CLLocation *montreal = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.521731 longitude:-73.628679];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance)